# How to show only new questions (with the new responsive theme)

Tags: discussion, responsive-design, newest-questions

As an administrator, I want to see all new questions that are posted to the site.

Starting from the site's homepage https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, how do I show only new questions, in as few clicks as possible, with the new November 2018 responsive theme?

Answer (score 5):

Two clicks are needed:

1. Click on the hamburger menu in the top left,
2. Click on "Questions".

[image]

Bookmarking the URL 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest probably is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the 'hamburger route' it is also possible to go to the bottom of the page where it says:

> Looking for more? Browse the **[complete list of questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions)**, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions.

Comment: Note to the curious, whom can see my other answer: I edited my answer within the time limit but for some reason it posted it as a new answer, so I deleted the other answer. The alternative would have been to delete this now correct answer and try again.